# How to write autorun programm in unix shell

Tags: unix, autorun

I am a newbie in unix shell. I want to write a script which would be create an autorun script , and when if some conditions  hold true autorun will  run. So i don't know what should i write in autorun file. Can u help me by advice what should i write or by link on some information , manuals about it.

Comment: What do you mean by "when if some conditions hold true"?

Comment: What do you mean by "autorun file"?

Comment: Especially, my program check is the flash disk connect to the pc. If yes at flash disk my programm create an autorun script which run every time when this flash disk is connect to any pc

Comment: autorun file/script like .inf in windows

Comment: I don't know what .inf is. Are you asking how to create a Windows autorun file? If so, why is this question tagged `unix`?

Comment: question about autorun in unix. file.inf this is just an analogy in windows

Comment: There's no such thing in unix.

Comment: So, i can't write autorun script ?

Comment: For starters, read the man page for your login shell.  It's probably `bash`.  Specifically investigate the `.profile` and other initialization files.  These are not autorun files, but they might point you in the right direction.

Comment: But seriously, read all of the documentation for the shell.